# possible unintended reference comparison to get a value comparison cast the right hand side to string

Tags: c#, database

Problem: The program runs, 

Next, the program ask me to login and I do so ERROR!

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException'
>   occurred in System.Data.dll at the da.Fill(dt); area possible
>   unintended reference comparison to get a value comparison cast the
>   right hand side to string @   if `(UserText.Text == dt.Rows[i]["CustID"] && PassText.Text == dt.Rows[i]["CustPassword"])`

Database:

[image]

I am trying to get a login form to work with the Microsoft Access Database.

```
 if (UserText.Text == dt.Rows[i]["CustID"] && PassText.Text == dt.Rows[i]["CustPassword"])
```

The code above is the area of which I have a problem.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    da = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select CustID, CustPassword From Customers", db);

    da.Fill(dt);
    for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (UserText.Text == dt.Rows[i]["CustID"] && PassText.Text == dt.Rows[i]["CustPassword"])
        {
            WelcomeCust f = new WelcomeCust();
            this.Hide();
            f.Show();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("FAILURE TRY AGAIN");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you better describe the problem? The question isn't clear. What do you expect to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: I have a windows 64 bit computer

Comment: What are the datatypes of: `UserText.Text`, `CustId`, `PassText.Text` and `CustPassword`?

Comment: Thats what I named my textboxes. UserText.Text and PassText.Text. Custpassword and CustID are in the database as the picture shows of which I have to gather to login with the database

Comment: Do you realize you're checking every customer and password each time you hit the button? You probably don't know whats happening because I'm guessing you only have 1 user during testing. Add more, you'll see. If the customer isn't the first one it'll say "Failure Try Again" for each user in the database. Learn to use the "Where" part of your SQL statement to limit to the correct user and don't loop through all of them. Actually it'll always say it, since you don't exit the loop when it succeeds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
if (UserText.Text.ToString() == dt.Rows[i]["CustID"].ToString() &&  
    PassText.Text.ToString() == dt.Rows[i]["CustPassword"].ToString())
```

or this

```
if ((string)UserText.Text == (string)dt.Rows[i]["CustID"] && 
    (string)PassText.Text == (string)dt.Rows[i]["CustPassword"])
```

and **Re-Build** your project. The error is because the **compile-time** type of `UserText.Text` is `object` and it fails.

Comment: Very Nice answer! Thank you, do you have any idea about the problem about the da.Fill();?

Comment: is the code working? if yes, there shouldn't be any issues with da.Fill();, else check your connection strings and db connection....